# Modify Nested JSON with jq

Tags: json, bash, sh, jq

I'm trying to modify nested JSON objects using the `jq <map>` function in a bash/shell script; something similar to [this blog entry](http://engineering.monsanto.com/2015/05/22/jq-change-json/) but attempting to adapt the examples here to nested objects.

The returned JSON to be modified as follows:

```
{
  "name": "vendor-module",
  "dependencies": {
    "abc": {
      "from": "abc@2.4.0",
      "resolved": "https://some.special.url",
      "version": "2.4.0"
    },
    "acme": {
      "from": "acme@1.2.3",
      "resolved": "<CHANGE_THIS>",
      "version": "1.2.3"
    }
  }
}
```

This would be my attempt:

```
modules="`node -pe 'JSON.parse(process.argv[1]).dependencies.$dependency' \
  "$(cat $wrapped)"`"
version="1.2.3"
resolved="some_url"

cat OLD.json | 
  jq 'to_entries | 
       map(if .dependencies[0].$module[0].from == "$module@$version"
          then . + {"resolved"}={"$resolved"}
          else . 
          end
         ) | 
      from_entries' > NEW.json
```

Obviously this doesn't work.  When I run the script the `NEW.json` is created but without modifications or returned errors. If I don't target a nested object (e.g., `"name": "vendor-module"`), The script works as expected. I am sure there is a way to do it using native bash and jq..?? Any help (with the proper escaping) will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Thnx from the help of [Charles Duffy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33554378/742030), and his suggestion of using `sponge`, The solution that works well for me is:

```
jq --arg mod "acme" --arg resolved "Some URL" \
   '.dependencies[$mod].resolved |= $resolved' \
   OLD.json | sponge OLD.json
```

Comment: Need a comma after the "from" for "acme" for this to be valid JSON, btw.

Comment: Waitaminute. You have `modules` in your input variables -- if you already know that you need to modify `acme`, not `abc`, why look at `from` and `version` at all?

Comment: Typo - Thnx. I quickly typed out this as an example - I didn't want to pollute the question with a bunch of none-pertinent code.

Comment: BTW, I strongly suggest building this kind of thing incrementally. If you were looking at the output of `jq '.dependencies | to_entries'`, that would show you the kind of data structure you need to work with (with contents under `.value`, and `.dependencies` not visible in present scope).

Comment: As another aside, I strongly suggest avoiding needless use of `cat`; programs fed input with `cat somefile | ...` get only a non-reversible pipe, whereas programs fed input with `... <somefile` have a proper, seekable file descriptor; it's both more efficient (always, on account of the lack of the pipeline, but doubly so if what you're implementing allows less memory usage, better parallelization or other algorithmic improvements when able to seek) and more flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your existing sample data, the following suffices:

```
jq --arg mod "acme" \
   --arg resolved "some_url" \
  '.dependencies[$mod].resolved=$resolved' \
  <in.json >out.json
```

...to filter on the `from`, by contrast:

```
jq --arg new_url "http://new.url/" \
   --arg target "acme@1.2.3" \
  '.dependencies=(.dependencies
                  | to_entries
                  | map(if(.value.from == $target)
                        then .value.resolved=$new_url
                        else . end)
                  | from_entries)' \
  <in.json >out.json
```

Comment: Works with the following edit: `jq --arg mod "acme" --arg resolved "some_url" '.dependencies[$mod].resolved=$resolved' OLD.json > NEW.json` Otherwise, `jq` didn't know what to to with it (e.g., THROWS: jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.3]
Usage: jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]

For a description of the command line options and
how to write jq filters (and why you might want to)
see the jq manpage, or the online documentation at
http://stedolan.github.com/jq) LOL  Thnx!

Comment: The obvious bug was a missing newline continuation after the second `--arg`; with that addressed, the code in the answer works for me when copied-pasted exactly as-is.

Comment: This seems more efficient: `jq --arg mod "acme" --arg resolved "Some URL" '.dependencies[$mod].resolved |= [$resolved]' OLD.json | tee OLD.json` Whats your take?

Comment: You mean with the `tee`? That's dangerous; both sides of the pipe are started at the same time, so whether `tee` opens its output file (and thus truncates it) before `jq` reads its input is simply a matter of luck.

Comment: ...if you want to be able to *reliably* edit a file in-place without the write-and-rename dance, look at the `sponge` tool from moreutils (which doesn't open the file whose name it's passed for output until after it's gotten an EOF from its stdin): https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/

Comment: Thnx for the info. I tried moreutils and I can see the stream in action and is definitely mush safer +2

Comment: Not quite clear on why you're using the update operator rather than the assignment operator here.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name of the dependency you want to update, you could just index into it.

```
$ jq --arg dep "$dep" --arg resolved "$resolved" \
    '.dependencies[$dep].resolved = $resolved' \
    OLD.json > NEW.json
```

Otherwise, to modify a dependency based on the name (or other property), search for the dependency and update.

```
$ jq --arg version "$version" --arg resolved "$resolved" \
    '(.dependencies[] | select(.version == $version)).resolved = $resolved' \
    OLD.json > NEW.json
```

Comment: Using `select` that way (to scope a mutating operation) is a very nice trick; +1.